# Example using Green's Functions for 1D Poisson Equation with Forced Oscillations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, greens-function

I've found lots of resources deriving the Green's function for the 1D Poisson Equation, but no examples actually solving a DE with them. As a result, I'm very confused setting up the integrals for different forcing functions.

> Consider the ODE with fixed boundary conditions $u(0)=0$ and $u(L)=L$:
>   $$\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}=\frac{-f(x)}{T}$$
>   It can be shown that the Green's function for this problem is
>   $$  G(x|\xi) =
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{(L-\xi)}{LT}x,  & \text{for $x<\xi$} \\
> \frac{(L-x)}{LT}\xi,  & \text{for $x>\xi$}
> \end{cases}$$
>   Hence $$u(x)=\int_0^LG(x|\xi)f(\xi) \ d\xi=\int_0^xG(x|\xi)f(\xi) \ d\xi+\int_x^LG(x|\xi)f(\xi) \ d\xi$$
>   Now consider the forcing function
>    $$f(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> f_0,  & \text{for $0<x<\frac{L}{2}$} \\
> -f_0,  & \text{for $\frac{L}{2}<x<L$}
> \end{cases}$$
>   find $u(x)$

So far, I've broken the problem into 2 regions and set up $u(x)$ separately in both regions. I get a reasonable answer except it's discontinuous at $\frac{L}{2}$. When deriving the Green's function, I thought we used continuity of the string as a condition.

It's a lot to type out, so if anyone is interested in seeing the details, I'll [link to a photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWCUp.jpg) and an [interactive graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kvq2p12ajd) of the solution.

Comment: Could you explain how the $T$ became a part of the Green function? You also missed the step where you transformed the problem to have homogeneous boundary conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Green's function

Your Green's function only makes sense if you reformulate the differential equation as
$$
-Tu''(x)=f(x).
$$
Then indeed the solution to $-T\frac{\partial^2 G(x|\xi)}{\partial\xi^2}=\delta(\xi-x)$, $0=G(x|0)=G(x|L)$ is
$$
G(x|\xi)=\begin{cases}
\frac{(L-x)\xi}{LT}  &\text{ for }\xi\le x,
\\
\frac{(L-\xi)x}{LT}  &\text{ for }\xi\ge x.
\end{cases}
$$

#### Homogeneous boundaries

To apply the Green function, you need homogeneous boundary conditions. To that end, select a function $u_0$ satisfying the boundary conditions and construct the equation for the difference. Here $u_0(x)=x$ and $v=u-u_0$ satisfies the same differential equation, as $v''=u''$.

#### Integrating the solution

The function $f$ that you insert is not a constant. It is a piecewise constant. This you have to include in your interval division.

Thus for $0\le x\le L/2\le L$ you get
\begin{align}
u(x)&=x+\int_0^L G(x|\xi)f(\xi)\,d\xi
\\
&=x+\int_0^x \frac{(L-x)\xi}{LT}f_0\,d\xi+\int_x^{L/2} \frac{(L-\xi)x}{LT}f_0\,d\xi+\int_{L/2}^L \frac{(L-\xi)x}{LT}(-f_0)\,d\xi
\\
&=x+\frac{f_0(L-x)x^2}{2LT}+\frac{f_0[-(L/2)^2+(L-x)^2]x}{2LT}-\frac{f_0(L/2)^2x}{2LT}
\\
&=x+\frac{f_0x(L-2x)}{4T} 
\end{align}
and similarly for $L/2\le x\le L$
\begin{align}
u(x)&=x+\int_0^L G(x|\xi)f(\xi)\,d\xi
\\
&=x+\int_0^{L/2} \frac{(L-x)\xi}{LT}f_0\,d\xi+\int_{L/2}^x \frac{(L-x)\xi}{LT}(-f_0)\,d\xi+\int_x^L \frac{(L-\xi)x}{LT}(-f_0)\,d\xi
\\
&=x+\frac{f_0(L-x)(L/2)^2}{2LT}-\frac{f_0(L-x)[x^2-(L/2)^2]}{2LT}-\frac{f_0(L-x)^2x}{2LT}
\\
&=x+\frac{f_0(L-x)(L-2x)}{4T}
\end{align}

Comment: I noticed you're just missing a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ in your second $u(x)$. It should be $x+\frac{f_0(L-x)(L-2x)}{4T}$. This makes so much sense now. Thank you.

Comment: Corrected. Thank you.